# Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, input, getelementsbytagname

I want to get all inputs from my website and show them in alert message.
However, it seems this script isn't working correctly and only shows the first input element.

What should I do?

```
function dotest() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    if (inputs.length > 0) {
        var s = document.URL + "\n";
        s += "-- Inputs list start --\n";
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var inputdata = inputs[i];
                var imputdatas = null;
                imputdatas += inputdata.name + ",";
                imputdatas += inputdata.id + ",";
                imputdatas += inputdata.type + ",";
                imputdatas += inputdata.value + "\n";
        }
        s += imputdatas;
        s += "-- End -\n\n";
    }
    if (s) {
        alert(s);
    }
}
dotest();
```

Comment: Is that really the best title you could think of?

Comment: @Pointy  Sorry. I 'll be careful for the next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add them all to `s` inside the loop, not after the loop

```
function dotest() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    if (inputs.length > 0) {
        var s = document.URL + "\n";
        s += "-- Inputs list start --\n";
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var inputdata = inputs[i];
            var imputdatas = '';
                imputdatas += inputdata.name + ",";
                imputdatas += inputdata.id + ",";
                imputdatas += inputdata.type + ",";
                imputdatas += inputdata.value + "\n";
            s += imputdatas;
        //  ^^^ needs to be here
        }
        s += "-- End -\n\n";
    }
    if (s) {
        alert(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: why should he do so ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek - It seemed so obvious I didn't explain it any more, once the loop has completed, only the last element is present in the local variable inside the loop.

Comment: didnt see it was local variable sorry

Comment: There really is no scope in a for loop, so the variable is hoisted, but the point is still the same, the loop sets a new value each time.